# Drag images and resize them on touch(iPhone)

Tags: iphone, ios, drag-and-drop, drawing

I am creating an app in which when user click on any object and when user tap on UIView, then that images should drop on the view, and on dragging that image in any direction it should be re-sized.
Anyone having any idea to do this, please let me know.
or Can I get any sample code for this?

Thanks

Comment: I have worked on begintouch, move and endtouch, but don't have any idea about dropping an object from a view to another and how to re-size them, I also know how to drag and drop objects within a single view.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

{

UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

if ([touch view] == photo) {

photo.center = touchLocation;

}

else if ([touch view] == photo1) {

    photo1.center = touchLocation;

}

}
```

or you can see in that link http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/iphone-DoubleImageMoveasd.html

Comment: Hello Jay this code works for dragging and dropping of the objects within the same view but what I want, to pick object from a different view and drop it in another view.